# Наследование модели Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Есть модель User которая наследует кастомную модель User одного из репозиториев. В наследованой модели прописан $fillable. Не могу понять как обнулить его в основной моделе User. Это нужно для того чтобы разработал $guard = [].

Comment: Область видимости не меняли? Пробовали обнулять в конструкторе?

Answer (score 0):

Перенес кастомную модель в основной каталог. Костыль конечно, при обновлении репозитория будут конфликты когда-то. Но лучше уж так чем указывать весь $fillable